# Issues with Prompt from react-router-dom not triggering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

A web application I am working on has a few pages that utilize Prompt to get user confirmation before they navigate away from the page.  Navigation in the page is generally done through calling history.push or history.goBack calls with history being gained from either react-router's useHistory hook or via wrapping the component working in with withRouter.  If I navigate to a page that utilizes Prompt within the web application and navigate away, it works as expected.  If I navigate to a page with a Prompt by typing in the URL and then navigate away, the Prompt does not work.

When examine the history object's location, there are differences between when the page is reached via within web app navigation vs typing in a URL.  The location will have a key field on on it when it is reached through internal navigation vs when it is reached via editing the URL.  But we do not see what on Prompt would require this to be a case to work.

The router being used from 'react-router-dom' is the BrowserRouter and the version of 'react-router-dom' being used is 5.1.2